# Loop through records from parent table where parentTableID in child table and

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have 2 tables complaints and tasks.

The complaintID is unique in the complaints table i.e the parent table and the it is the foreign key in the task table.

So one complaint can have multiple tasks therefore in the task table you can have the same complaintID many times.

#### I want to display all fields from the complaints table when ALL related task have the status as complete

I have tried this but is does not work completely because if a complaint has 4 tasks and only 1 task is marked as complete then it pulls that complaint:

```
SELECT * FROM complaints WHERE complaintID IN 
(SELECT * FROM tasks WHERE completed="yes") ORDER BY deadline
```

I would grateful if someone could help me with this one.

Comment: Could you provide the structure of your tables and some sample data?

Comment: hint: the list of complaints with all tasks completed, equals the list of all complaints minus those for which exist a non-completed task.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it like this also

```
select complaints.*, tasks.* from complaints, tasks where 
complaints.complaintID=tasks.complaintID and tasks.completed='yes' and 
complaints.complaintID NOT IN (select complaintID from tasks where completed='no')
```

The table Structure used was :

```
CREATE TABLE complaints (
  complaintID INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
  content VARCHAR(255),
  deadline datetime
  );

CREATE TABLE tasks (
  tasksid INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
  complaintID INT,
  completed ENUM ('yes','no')
  );

INSERT INTO complaints(content,deadline) VALUES ('complaint1', NOW()+INTERVAL 3 day), ('complaint2',NOW()+INTERVAL 8 day);

INSERT INTO tasks (complaintID, completed) VALUES(1,'no'), (1,'yes'), (2,'no');
```

I used the table structure from @Mr. Radical, from his SQL FIDDLE.

Hope it helps

Comment: Thanks. I tried this but it just pulls anything with one task completed which was the problem I was having.

Comment: Okay. Now I understand the question. Let me tweak that .

Comment: Still the same results :(
this ting is I can't understand how it can be so difficult to code but soo easy to explain

Comment: Excellent this is the only answer that works. 
Thank you soo much its exactly what I was onto but missed the last part totally :)

Answer (score 0):

```
select  *
from    complaints c
where   not exists
        (
        select  *
        from    tasks t
        where   t.ComplaintID = c.ComplaintID
                and t.Completed <> 'yes'
        )
```

Comment: 'complaints table
    ++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
    complaintID
    staffID
    description
    deadlineDate
    --------------------------

    Tasks Table
    +++++++++++++++++++++++++
    taskID
    complaintID
    staffID
    task
    completed {yes/no}
    deadline
    completedDate'

Comment: Hi Andomar, this query does not seem correct because it find anything that is that yes. I'll try it now

Answer (score 0):

You want to look up only the foreign key attribute on the 'inner' table. So, write it like this:
 SELECT * FROM complaints WHERE complaintID IN 
 (SELECT complaintId*
 FROM tasks WHERE completed="yes") ORDER BY deadline
* or whatever your foreign key is on the task table

Comment: this does not work it what I was doing before. thanks for trying

Comment: Thanks for the effort, This does return the same results I was getting before

Answer (score 0):

**EDITED**

Try this:

```
 SELECT * FROM complaints 
 WHERE NOT EXISTS 
       (SELECT complaintid 
       FROM tasks 
       WHERE complaintid 
       in (SELECT complaintID 
           FROM tasks 
           WHERE tasks.complaintID = complaints.complaintid 
           and completed = 'no') 
       )ORDER BY deadline;
```

[SQL FIDDLE DEMO](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/f6055/14)

This is the table structure and sample data if have used to test my answer above.

```
CREATE TABLE complaints (
  complaintID INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
  content VARCHAR(255),
  deadline datetime
  );

CREATE TABLE tasks (
  tasksid INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
  complaintID INT,
  completed ENUM ('yes','no')
  );

INSERT INTO complaints(content,deadline) VALUES ('complaint1', NOW()+INTERVAL 3 day), ('complaint2',NOW()+INTERVAL 8 day),('complaint3', NOW()+INTERVAL 3 day);

INSERT INTO tasks (complaintID, completed) VALUES(1,'no'), (1,'yes'), (2,'yes'), (1,'no'), (1,'yes'),  (1,'yes'), (2,'no'), (3,'yes'), (3, 'yes');
```

Comment: This would return a complaint where only some of the tasks are completed.  I think the OP said that all tasks had to be completed.

Comment: In your fiddle link, ComplaintID = 1 should not be returned because it has an incomplete task

Comment: @Andomar I agree I made a mistake in my first answer. I think I have corrected it with my last answer. http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/b06e3/15

Comment: Thanks for trying but it still return records where 1 task is not marked as complete

Comment: @jam_k I am a bit confused but if the answer above works for you great. Remember to add order by deadline to the accepted answer. Otherwise you won't get your desired results. You can if you want to reward my effort up vote my answer.

Comment: thanks but it did not work completely it pulled other results too

Comment: @jam_k check this: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/f6055/15 . I changed my answer after your first comment.

Comment: I tested the reviewed code and it mostly works but I put completed='started' and it pulls that too and also complaints with no task assigned to them so its not quiet correct. However the answer I have marked as correct did not pull that one.

Comment: it says I need 15 points to vote u youpr answer :(

THANK YOU FOR YOUR EFFORT! I REALLY appreciate it! 
I have been trying since yesterday and just could not figure it out.